# Why The value for annotation attribute Rest.rootUrl must be a constant expression?

Tags: java, android, rest, android-annotations

Im using [Android Annotations Framework](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations), specially for Rest Integration. 
I have the following code.

An interface for Host configuration

```
public interface Host {
    public String URL = "http://192.168.2.137";
}
```

And the annotated Interface for Rest communication.

```
@Rest(rootUrl = Host.URL, converters = { MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.class })
public interface RestClient {
    @Get("/entities.json")
    Entity[] allEntities();
}
```

and my question is, **Why the value for annotation attribute Rest.rootUrl must be a constant expression? and how can i use a String resource for Rest.rootUrl ?**

I wish to do something like

```
@EBean
public class Host{
    @StringRes
    String URL;
}
```

But is impossible with the RestClient interface.

The idea is to handle a localized rest application, suppose distinct URLs by language

```
http://en.myapp.com
http://es.myapp.com
```

I know that an Java Interface must have final properties, but, there are a way to handle a localized rootUrl value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jon is right about annotation values, but Android Annotations actually does give you a way to dynamically set the root url for a RestClient.

Just omit the rootUrl attribute from the annotation and add a method to the interface:

```
void setRootUrl(String rootUrl);
```

Just remember that you'll need to call `RestClient.setRootUrl(url)` at some point in your app before you actually use RestClient.

More info at https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Rest%20API#rest

Comment: I was pretty shure that setRootUrl(String rootUrl) had not been in AndroidAnnotations before (2.7.1), seems like a new feature (3), i am right?. Very thanks!

Comment: I think it may have been in 2.6 - the pull request that added it is about a year old, but either way, it's there now :)

Answer (score 2):

> Why the value for annotation attribute Rest.rootUrl must be a constant expression?

This isn't really an Android question in particular, or about those specific annotations. *All* annotation values in Java have to be constant expressions - because those values are baked into the classfile *at compilation time*.

From the [JLS section 9.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.7):

> An element type T is commensurate with an element value V if and only if one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - T is an array type E[] and either:
>
>   - V is an ElementValueArrayInitializer and each ElementValue (analogous to a VariableInitializer in an array initializer) in V is commensurate with E; or
>   - V is an ElementValue that is commensurate with E.
> - The type of V is assignment compatible (§5.2) with T, and furthermore:
>
>   - If T is a primitive type or String, and V is a constant expression (§15.28).
>   - V is not null.
>   - If T is Class, or an invocation of Class, and V is a class literal (§15.8.2).
>   - If T is an enum type, and V is an enum constant.